# How to add an extra column to Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

Love this debugging tool.  It would be great if I could see how long each call takes as a column rather than having to click each individual item and look at its statistics.

I didn't see any options to add this column.  Is there a way to do it via a config file or a script?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There sure is.

In Fiddler, go to Rules -> Customize Rules...

Now do a find for "onBeforeResponse", and in that method, add the following line of code at the bottom:

```
oSession["ui-customcolumn"] = oSession["X-TTLB"];
```

Should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 14):

I tried the other answers but none of them give me the actual overall elapsed time, as TTLB is not always what we want.  The Fiddler help page @Eric Lawrence mentioned has the better answer.  Hit Ctrl+R for the script editor, then add this code to the Handlers class:

```
public static BindUIColumn("Time Taken")
       function CalcTimingCol(oS: Session){
         var sResult = String.Empty;
         if ((oS.Timers.ServerDoneResponse > oS.Timers.ClientDoneRequest))
         {
           sResult = (oS.Timers.ServerDoneResponse - oS.Timers.ClientDoneRequest).ToString();
         }
         return sResult;
       }
```

This also has the added benefit of sorting correctly.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, this worked great for me. After I added to CustomRules.js I re-started Fiddler and the column appeared at the far right. My Fiddler version (installed yesterday): v2.4.4.3. Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

UPDATE October 2012 this appears to be built in now.

Click Rules -> Performance -> Show Time-To-Last-Byte

The next request will show the ttlb in the custom column.

UPDATE May 2013 - I upgraded to Fiddler 4.4.4.4 Beta and found that this option is no longer available.

Comment: wierd how a built in option can't figure out how to title the column nicely :-( but works well otherwise

Comment: FYI, The sort on this column isn't working--it incorrectly sorts by string order (in at least 2.4.2.6)

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/configurecolumns.asp for other options.

Answer (score 1):

The TTLB is there, just found it. Right click on the columns above the urls, click customise columns, in collection, select session timers, in Timer Name: select TTLB. Working for me, cheers.